# Rails: "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller:

```
Article.author_ids_in(params[:filters][:author_ids])
```

This of course returns an error ("You have a nil object...") if those particular params have not been passed.  Here is the model method:

```
def self.author_ids_in(filters)
  unless filters.nil?
    where(:author_id + filters)
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

As you can see, I'm already prepared for a nil object, so how can I get Ruby to allow nil to be passed?

Comment: Are you sure that your `params[:filters]` is not `nil`? Please give full error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

params[:filters] is most likely nil so it's raising an exception when you try to go into it to get [:author_ids]

Either check before you call the scope, or rescue the exception:

```
begin
  Article.author_ids_in(params[:filters][:author_ids])
rescue NoMethodError
  # do something else here
end
```